# np.size in pandas groupby Transform is slow (optimization needed)

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a very large DataFrame according *df* below. I apply a boolean filtering according to example code, and then calculate number of times the groupby-variable has elements in the filtered DataFrame. Given the size of my DataFrame (several million rows), it takes some time to do this count operation. Could someone give me a pro tip on how this operation could be optimized to be quicker?

Thanks in advance!

/swepab

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'agg_var1' : [i for i in ['a'] * 3] + [i for i in ['b'] * 7] + [i for i in ['c'] * 5] + [i for i in ['d'] * 5] + [i for i in ['e'] * 2]
               ,'num_var1' : [i for i in range(1,23)]
               ,'num_var2' : [np.nan,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,5,5,6,6,6,7,8,9,9,9,9,10]
               ,'num_var3' : np.random.random_sample(22)
               ,'d_var1' : pd.date_range('20140101', freq = '1m', periods = 22).strftime("%Y%m")
              })


df['count_var1'] = df[df.num_var1 > 10][['agg_var1', 'd_var1']].groupby('agg_var1').transform(np.size)
```

Comment: How much time does it actually take?

Comment: It takes minutes, and its also done on a number of DataFrames in the same fashion so the time waiting increases.

Comment: This might decrease the time a little bit `df['count_var1'] = df[df.num_var1 > 10].groupby('agg_var1')['d_var1'].transform('size')` but I don't think you can get much better than that using only pandas. Maybe tag numpy?

Comment: If you have a large number of groups, adding `sort=False` to the `groupby` function should already save some time.

Comment: The 'size' implementation actually made it a bit slower, buy using `sort = False` gave me a small improvement of a couple of % when using `%timeit`

Comment: took me 18 sec when I tried on a 26 million row dataframe. 50% of the total time is  used on assigning the result back. You might want to filter out the rows and put it in another DF. Then groupby/transform. In this case, assigning back to the new DF takes no time.

Answer (score 0):

I created a function which performsthe groupby and transform part on the dataframe passed to it and returns a series.

```
def my_fun(my_df):
    return my_df.groupby('agg_var1').transform(np.size)
df['new_col']=my_fun(df[df.num_var1 > 10][['agg_var1', 'd_var1']])
```

The timeit performance shows improvement of 0.03 ms improvement on data set of length 29.

Please try if it is helpful to you.